# why is my result incorrect for mod in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, expression, division, modulo

```
RIGHT("0" & (SUM(Fields!TotalTimeSpent.Value MOD 60, "Group3")), 2)
```

Value is 273, I am getting 93 returned instead of expected 33.

[image]

expressions purpose is to calculate time spent, here is the complete expression.  This works on almost all entries, this is the only example I have seen where it is adding the values instead of modding.

```
= IIF(FLOOR(SUM(Fields!TotalTimeSpent.Value / 60, "Group3")) = 0, "00", FLOOR(SUM(Fields!TotalTimeSpent.Value / 60, "Group3"))) & ":" & RIGHT("0" & (SUM(Fields!TotalTimeSpent.Value MOD 60, "Group3")), 2)
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to do the MOD calculation *after* running the SUM? So the expression would be `RIGHT("0" & (SUM(Fields!TotalTimeSpent.Value, "Group3") MOD 60), 2)`. Because if I run just `RIGHT("0" & (273 MOD 60), 2)`, it gives me the expectedresult of 33.

Comment: Awesome - yes...  oversight on my part, thanks!  Put this in as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Okidoki, done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean to do the MOD calculation after running the SUM? So the expression would be:

```vb
=RIGHT("0" & (SUM(Fields!TotalTimeSpent.Value, "Group3") MOD 60), 2)
```

As a test, if I run just:

```vb
=RIGHT("0" & (273 MOD 60), 2)
```

It gives me the expectedresult of 33.